# Android Google Maps API v2 placing markers on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

There is a map on which the markers are placed by downloading the location value from the database. But visually appear only after activation `onResume()`. Here is a method for placing markers

```
public void place(){

      for (int i = 0; i<user_sex.length; i++){
            //someone = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(xx[i], yy[i])).title("Вы здесь!");
            if (user_sex[i]==1){

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
            list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);

            }
            if (user_sex[i]==2){
                //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
            }else{
                if(xx[i]!=0 && yy[i]!=0 && (user_sex[i] < 1)){
                    //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
                }
                }
            //map.addMarker(someone);
        }
  }
```

But in this case, I can see them without restarting the activity

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(x, y)).zoom(16).build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


        place();
        this.onResume();
```

But this decision entails problems with the management card - if you move the camera, it's returns to the place, and when scaling - returns to the zoom (16). There is a solution? My onResume() below

```
@Override
  protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10,
            locationListener);
        checkEnabled();
  }
```

And full class MapActivity below:

```
 package com.pavloid21.vk;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.pavloid21.vk.R;
import com.pavloid21.vk.ProfileActivity;
import com.sbstrm.appirater.Appirater;
import com.startad.lib.SADView;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity{

     SharedPreferences spref, mpref;
     Editor editor;
     Thread thrd;
     boolean flag;
     HttpResponse response = null;
     String token_user;
     int sex;
     long usr;
     long ID;
     static double x, y, lastX, lastY;
     static int count = 0;
     SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
     private LocationManager locationManager;
      GoogleMap map;
      Map<LatLng, Integer> list = new HashMap();
      final String TAG = "myLogs";
      private ProgressDialog pDialog;
      long[] vkIDs;
      int[] user_sex;
      double[] xx;
      double[] yy;
      String[] name;
      String[] m;
      MarkerOptions someone;
      String nm;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        vkIDs = new long[100];
        user_sex = new int[100];
        xx = new double[100];
        yy = new double[100];
        name = new String[100];



        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        if (map == null) {
          finish();
          return;
        }


      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume(){
          super.onResume();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10,
                locationListener);
            checkEnabled();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
      }

      private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
          @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              showLocation(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
              checkEnabled();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
              checkEnabled();
              showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));



            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
              if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                  Log.d("loction CHECK","Status: GPS "+ String.valueOf(status));

              } else if (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                  Log.d("loction CHECK","Status: NET "+ String.valueOf(status));
              }
            }
      };

      private void showLocation(Location location) {
            if (location == null)
              return;
            if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d("loction CHECK","Status: GPS "+ formatLocation(location));

            } else if (location.getProvider().equals(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d("loction CHECK","Status: NET "+ formatLocation(location));
            }

            x = location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();


            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(x, y)).title("Вы здесь!");
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

            Appirater.appLaunched(this);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                   if (list.containsKey(marker.getPosition())){
                   int i = list.get(marker.getPosition());

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                   ProfileActivity.setID(vkIDs[i]);
                   startActivity(intent);

                   }
                }
            });
            if (count < 1) {

              map.addMarker(marker);

              mpref = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              flag = mpref.getBoolean("geo", true);

              if(flag == true){
              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void  run(){

                              DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                                ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();  
                                spref = getSharedPreferences("SETTING", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                if (spref.contains("IDUSER")){
                                usr = spref.getLong("IDUSER", 0);
                                nm = spref.getString("NAME", "");
                                sex = spref.getInt("SEX", 0);
                                //token_user = spref.getString("TOKEN", "");
                                //sex = spref.getInt("SEX", 0);
                                //nm = spref.getString("NAME", "");
                                }
                                HttpGet http;
                                http = new HttpGet("http://hdwallpapers.orisale.ru//set_mylocation.php?vkid="+usr+"&name="+nm+"&sex="+sex+"&x="+ x +"&y="+ y);

                                Log.d("SEX!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", ""+sex);
                                try {
                                    String response = hc.execute(http, res);
                                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                }).start();
              } else {}
              Thread getPeopleThrd = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://hdwallpapers.orisale.ru//get_around.php?&x="+ x +"&y="+ y);

                        JSONArray array = null;
                      try {
                        array = json.getJSONArray("locations");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        try {
                            JSONObject around = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            vkIDs[i] = (around.getLong("vkid"));
                            user_sex[i] = (around.getInt("sex"));
                            xx[i] = (around.getDouble("x"));
                            yy[i] = (around.getDouble("y"));
                            name[i] = around.getString("name");
                            //name[i] = frnd_name(vkIDs[i]);
                            //Log.d("",name[i]);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    }
                });
                getPeopleThrd.start(); 
            count += 1;

            };



            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(x, y)).zoom(16).build();
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            //frnd_name(usr);
            place();
            this.onResume();
          }

      public void place(){

          for (int i = 0; i<user_sex.length; i++){
                //someone = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(xx[i], yy[i])).title("Вы здесь!");
                if (user_sex[i]==1){

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
                list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);

                }
                if (user_sex[i]==2){
                    //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                    list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
                }else{
                    if(xx[i]!=0 && yy[i]!=0 && (user_sex[i] < 1)){
                        //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                    list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
                    }
                    }
                //map.addMarker(someone);
            }
      }



      private String formatLocation(Location location) {
            if (location == null)
              return "";
            return String.format(
                "Coordinates: lat = %1$.4f, lon = %2$.4f, time = %3$tF %3$tT",
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), new Date(
                    location.getTime()));



          }

      private void checkEnabled() {
            Log.d(" ...  ", "Enabled: "+ locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
            Log.d(" ...  ", "Enabled: "+ locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));

                      }


      private void frnd_name(final long vkid){
          ID = vkid;
          Thread getName = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=" + ID);

                    JSONArray array = null;
                  try {
                    array = json.getJSONArray("response");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject around = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nameFrnd = around.getString("first_name");
                        nameFrnd = nameFrnd + " " + around.getString("last_name");
                        nm = nameFrnd;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }

                }
            });
          getName.start();
          if (getName.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED){
              for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                  name[i] = nm;
              }
          }

      }   

}
```

Comment: from where you are calling place(); method

Comment: @Achuthan, this method I call within the class. It is contained within the same class. And contains the code from the first box in my previous post.

Comment: @Achuthan place() calling from onCreate() of the same activity

Comment: you need to put on your full code to get help...       since  you have used many functions like checkenabled() and we don't know where is it from...          just put your full class

Comment: @Achuthan I add an entirely class code in question. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Achuthan help me please! (;__; )

Comment: Sorry for the delay man my account has suspended for some reason so that i can't post the answer for some time..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the marker inside

```
    private void showLocation(Location location) {
}
```

You are calling the **`showLocation()`** method from the Location Listener...

The location listener will be triggered only when you asks the location mager to provide update, that means you need to make the statement...

```
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
```

Since you are initializing the location manager to provide update in the **`onResume`** method, so that only your marker's are placed after calling the **`onResume`** method...

You can initialize the location manager to provide update in the **`onStart`**  method

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mLocationClient.connect();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    }
```

You don't need to write the **`onResume()`** method..

Hope this will help you.........!